# How to tell if a function has rotational symmetry?

Tags: functions, symmetric-functions

How to spot rotational symmetry on(or in, of?) a function? If I have the function $f(x)={{5a^2+6ax+9x^2}\over {a+3x}}$, how can I know it has rotational symmetry about the point $(-{a\over 3},0)$?

Is there a general method to detect rotational symmetry?

Comment: "Rotation" is not defined in 1D. Do you mean mirroring ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think the OP means point symmetry around a center...

Answer (score 4):

Simplify it to 
$$
f(x)={{5a^2+6ax+9x^2}\over {a+3x}}=\frac{4a^2}{a+3x} + {{a^2+6ax+9x^2}\over {a+3x}}=\frac{4a^2}{a+3x} + {{(a+3x)^2}\over {a+3x}}\\
=\frac{4a^2}{a+3x} + (a+3x)
$$
and substitute $y=a+3x$ then
$$
f(y)=\frac{4a^2}{y}+y
$$
which has the following property:
$$
f(-y)=-\frac{4a^2}{y} -y = -f(y)
$$
which means that $f(y)$ is an [odd function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions#Odd_functions), point symmetric around the origin, hence $f(x)$ is point symmetric around $0=a+3x$ so your symmetric center is shift accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

$$f(-\frac{2a}3-x)={{5a^2+6a\left(-\frac{2a}3-x\right)+9\left(-\frac{2a}3-x\right)^2}\over {a+3\left(-\frac{2a}3-x\right)}}={{5a^2+6ax+9x^2}\over {-a-x}}=-f(x).$$